# How many subfields are there between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[16]{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\alpha = \sqrt[16]{2}$ be a positive real number and $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ be the algebraic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ by alpha. Find the number of intermediate field $F$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq F \subseteq K$.

Ok. I have an ugly solution. Suppose that $F$ is such an intermediate field. Consider the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, say $f(x)$. Clearly $f(x) | x^{12}-2$. Noting that all the fields under consideration are contained in the real field, and $$x^{16}-2 = \left(x-\sqrt[16]{2}\right) \left(x+\sqrt[16]{2}\right) \left(-x^2+2^{9/16}
   x-\sqrt[8]{2}\right) \left(x^2+\sqrt[8]{2}\right) \left(x^2+2^{9/16} x+\sqrt[8]{2}\right)
   \left(-x^4+2^{5/8} x^2-\sqrt[4]{2}\right) \left(x^4+2^{5/8} x^2+\sqrt[4]{2}\right)$$ and observing that all the coefficients are of the form $\alpha^k$, I have concluded that
(*) $F$ should be of the form $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha^t]$, $t=0,1,2,4,8,16$.
My question is the following;

> Is there an argument to say (*) without actual fatorization?

or it could be great if we one can prove the following

> All the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}]$ are of the form $\mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{1}{2^k}}]$, $0 \le k \le n$.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something of this kind?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory

Comment: I don't think Galois theory is useful here, Computing the Galois group of the splitting field of x^12 - 2 is very difficult and ends up with a semidirect product. The work to do that is much harder than producing the factorization that you did.

Comment: I don't think t should be 16, it should be the divisors of 12.

Comment: The 8th and 16th powers are redundant, generating the same subfields as the 4th power (i.e. as the cube root of $2$), but the 3rd and 6th powers (4th and square roots of $2$) seem to generate different subfields from those listed.

Comment: @rain1 It is not that difficult. A semidirect product is quite simple to understand and to manipulate. The method with Galois theory is more intrinsic and easier to generalize to other problems. Definitely a superior way of doing it. Also there is the tag `galois-theory` present, so the OP seems to know it.

Comment: There are exactly 4 proper subfields, namely those generated by $a^2$, $a^3$, $a^4$ and $a^6$ (but this is obtained using the factorization).

Comment: @Ned Now I have fixed the exponents.

Comment: @ahulpke There has been typo. Now I have fixed it.

Comment: @seoneo looks like a couple more of those $12$'s should be changed to $16$ 

Comment: Are you trying to use Galois theory to tune a piano??

Comment: @Vincent During the typing the question, I expected a solution which make use of the theory of Galois. However, it turns out that calculating the full galois group of the minimal polynomial requires some efforts which amounts at least the factorization of the polynomial. If my solution below is correct, by the way, one solution does not use the theory that much.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha = 2^{1/12}$ and let $\zeta_{12}$ be a 12th root of unity.

$\mathbb Q(\zeta_{12}, \alpha)$ is the splitting field of $X^{12}-2$ and has Galois group $V_4 \rtimes C_{12}$. (Calculating this Galois group is rather difficult and involves more work than the factorization you have already done).

By the Galois correspondence, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ corresponds to the subgroup $C_{12}$, and its subfields correspond to subgroups of $C_{12}$.

Therefore we can deduce that the subfields are $\mathbb Q(\alpha), \mathbb Q(\alpha^2), \mathbb Q(\alpha^3), \mathbb Q(\alpha^4), \mathbb Q(\alpha^6), \mathbb Q(\alpha^{12}) = \mathbb Q$.

---

Let $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$. We will do one example explicitly. $C_4 \le C_{12}$. By the Galois correspondence the fixed field $|K : K^{C_4}| = |C_4| = 4$.

Let $\sigma \alpha = \zeta_{12} \alpha$ so that $\alpha$ generates $C_{12}$. Then $\sigma^3$ generates our $C_4$ subgroup.

Notice that $\sigma^3 \alpha^4 = (\zeta_{12}^3 \alpha)^4 = \alpha^4$. So $\alpha^4$ is fixed by $\sigma_3$.

Thus $\mathbb Q(\alpha^4)$ is our subfield of index 4 corresponding to $C_4$.

Comment: In the title the question, indeed, asks about the twelfth root. But the rest of the question is about the sixteenth root :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Many thanks and excuse me.

Comment: Many thanks for your interesting solution!

Answer (score 2):

We will prove the following.

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\alpha = \sqrt[n]{2}$. Then the number of subfields of the field $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is $\tau(n)$ and the subfields are precisely those $\mathbb{Q}\left[ \alpha^d \right]$ where $d|n$.

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ let $d$ be a positive divisor of $n$. Let $F = \mathbb{Q}\left[\alpha^d\right]$. We have $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{n}{d}$ because $x^{\frac{n}{d}}-2$ is irreducible by the Eisenstein criterion. It follows that $[K:F]=d$. Now suppose that $E$ is a subfield of $K$ with $[K:E] =d$. Note that $K=E[\alpha]$. Let $f(x)=irr_{\alpha,E}(x)$. Then $f(x)|x^2-2$ and its degree is $d$. Hence the zeros of $f(x)$ are of the form $\alpha \zeta$ where $\zeta$s are some root of unity. Multiplying all the roots of $f(x)$ we have $\alpha^d Z$ where $Z$ is some root of unity again. Note that all the fields under consideration are some subfields of the field of the real numbers. Therefore we have $Z= \pm 1$. This tells us that $\alpha^d \in E$. Hence we have that $F$ is a subfield of $E$ with $[E:F]=1$ which completes the proof.